# download Python 3.3 modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, easy-install

I am running python 3.3 on my Mac with mountain lion. I am trying to download the twitter api. Most sources say use pip, which requires easy_install, which apparently I do not have. When in the terminal I run n`ew-host-2:~ lego90511$ easy_install pip`and in response I get error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-25628.write-test'
>
> The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
>   the distutils default setting) was:
>
> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
>
> Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
>   installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
>   as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
>   access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
>   directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
>   variable.
>
> For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
>   documentation at:
>
> http://peak.telecommunity.com/EasyInstall.html
>
> Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues here. One is the permissions issue as mentioned by @garnertb. pip tries to install in the site packages of the Python install which is owned by root.

The other issue is that you are installing into Apple's python 2.7 and you say you want python 3.3. [enter link description here](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/#installation)The reason for this is that easy_install includes n its text the directory of the python that it comes from. Just typing easy_install gets you the first on the path which in this case looks like `/usr/bin/easy_install` which is the Apple installed one. you get the easy_install for python 3.3 you have to give its full path which depends on how you installed python 3.3

The [pip install page](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html) says

> Warning We advise against using easy_install to install pip

Its suggested methods are to install virtualenv as per [this](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/#installation) unfortunately even though both written by the same group they seem to each say start with the other. In virtualenv take the source code route, which is the third and fourth entries there after the pip examples.

The global install is

```
$ curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ cd virtualenv-X.X
$ [sudo] python setup.py install
```

On OSX I installed python and thus pip via Macports so as to get easy installation of libraries that require complex C builds and also make this bootstrapping easier as this has been done for you.

Comment: Ok when through the terminal and go to '/Libary/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3' So I have located python3.3 so how do I specify that I want to use its easy_install, that is assuming it comes with it. I tried running easy_install while sitting in 3.3 and python3.3 deeper in and got the same thing, so is there a specific way for me to specify 'this' python?

Comment: The first notable thing on the virtualenv is how to install it with pip, so I'm a little confused as the the purpose of it, and second I'm not really sure what you are saying with the last line

Comment: @EasilyBaffled - yes not a very satisfacory page - I'll remove that.

Comment: which then leaves the SO link, which doesn't really explain how to redirect to 3.3's easy_install, or have I missed it?

Comment: I can't help but be a problem, when I plug in tar xvfz virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz I end up getting tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors. And on a different note, is it possible to use curl(I admit i know nothing of it) on pip directly

Comment: X.X needs tobe replaced by the exact version number ue 3.3 (it is why I use macports `port install py33-pip` just works ALso why I don't exactly answer as I have not struggled through this way for a long time.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I used the distribute package from the SO link you put up. I found pip I just can't figure out how to get it to work but that is a topic for another questions.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your question, this could be a permissions issue.  Try installing using sudo:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```